# Loading data into IBM Analytics for Apache Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, ibm-cloud, analytics-for-hadoop, analytics-for-apache-hdp

I have created a service in **IBM bluemix** for **Analytics for Apache Hadoop**, And now trying to access the biginsights console as mentioned in this [tutorial](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/infosphere/hadoop/trials.html), But not able to see anything like that in real case, now I am not sure how can i load data into Analytics for Apache Hadoop? How can i use sqoop here to load RDBMS data? Any help will be appreciated, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The Analytics for Hadoop service was upgraded to BigInsights v4 about a month ago, this is why you see a different UI to what is on some of the online tutorials as those are based on the previous BigInsights v3.

You would upload your data to HDFS for your Analytics for Hadoop service using the webHDFS REST API first, and then it should be available for you in BigSheets via the DFS Files tab shown in your screenshot.

The data you upload would be under /user/biblumix in HDFS as this is the username your are provided when you create a Analytics for Hadoop service in Bluemix.

To use the webHDFS REST API and other information about the service, see [these](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/AnalyticsforHadoop/index.html#analyticsforhadoop_data) instructions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. Here i can upload some files/string types.. Is there any way to directly upload my RDBMS data(say MySQL) to HDFS? may be with help of Sqoop or something. I am not able find any tutorial that describes how to use sqoop with IBM's Analytics for Apache Hadoop,

Comment: I don't have any experience with Sqoop but the Analytics for Hadoop service only allows access to HDFS via the RESTful API rather than JDBC.